What’s the curve rank of secp256k1?
Simple question. I failed to find how compute the rank of an elliptic curve using the version of online tools like SageMath or Pari/gp since it’s the only thing I have access to…
So elliptic curves have a something that is called a rank. What’s the rank of secp256k1 or how to compute it using SageMath or Pari/gp ?

From what I can find about this concept, rank of an elliptic curve is only defined for elliptic curves over the rational numbers.
Since secp256k1 is an elliptic curve defined over a finite field, the term does not apply.
The elliptic curve y2 = x3 + 7, over the rational numbers, has rank 0.

I was indeed talking about prime fields. While of course, it doesn’t apply to Bitcoin I was reading this paper that propose a practical algorithm for solving discrete logarithms if the underlying curve has rank 1. So I was curious to know what was the rank of secp256k1.

I can't access that paper, but are you sure it's about solving ECDLP over a finite field?

Yes I am. The full pdf is here https://pdfupload.io/docs/4ef85049
